# Why isn't the least squares predictor $\Phi(\Phi^\top\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top$ simply the identity matrix?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, linear, mathematical-statistics

Given target vector $y$. Want to predict it using linear regression $h(w) = w^Tx$

Let $\Phi$ be the least squares matrix, i.e., $\Phi = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^\top \\ \vdots\\ x_n^\top \end{bmatrix}$

The least squares prediction is,

$$\hat y = \Phi(\Phi^\top\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top y$$

But why isn't  $\Phi(\Phi^\top\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top$  simply the identity matrix?

Observe,
 $\Phi(\Phi^\top\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^\top = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}{\Phi^\top}^{-1})\Phi^\top = I I = I$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of $\Phi$ isn't necessarily defined since it does not have to be square. You can't distribute the inverse of a matrix in that way. Wikipedia has a decent page about [invertible matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

This [wordpress post](https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/derivation-of-ols-normal-equations/) has an easy to read derivation of the normal equations as well.